# Why is my output printing on two lines?

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a file path out of a predetermined path and a variable which is a folder inside the pre determined path.

The predetermined part of the path is `/sys/kernel/scst_tgt/targets/iscsi/`

The next folder is an address for an iSCSI target like `iqn.2011-08.com.solignis:datastore2`

Then the last part is something like `/enabled` which is a file that tells the state of the target.

When I try to print the full path with the variable `$target_name` being replaced with the name of the iSCSI target. The resulting output looks like this

```
/sys/kernel/scst_tgt/targets/iscsi/iqn.2011-08.com.solignis:datastore2
/enabled
```

It puts the enabled part on a new line. I can't figure out what is going on

Here is the code for the sub routine I was working on:

```
sub target_enabled {
    my $target_name = shift;
    my $target_state_file = "/sys/kernel/scst_tgt/targets/iscsi/$target_name/enabled";
    print "$target_state_file\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have a newline at the end of `$target_name`. So:

```
chomp $target_name;
```

And if that doesn't work (because you may have for example `\r\n` from a windows file):

```
$target_name =~ s/\s+\z//;
```

Comment: `chomp`ing $target_name fixed it, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TLP - "more code than necessary" is an awfully short distance from "not golfy enough". Using @_ without assigning to variables leads to significantly less readable and extremely less maintainable code and should not be encouraged as practice, sorry.

Comment: The version I posted was an in between, much more is going into the sub. I was just proving the concept by printing it.

Comment: @DVK You have a point there. I usually try to remove extra variables if I can, but I guess I went one step too far there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $target_name has a line feed at the end. Check subroutine caller's argument.

(EDIT:) You can use `chop` to remove the line feed if it is always there.

```
chop $target_name;
```

Comment: [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is the safe version of `chop`.

Comment: So unless I need chop specificly, chomp would be better?

Comment: `chop` removes the last character in the string, no matter what it is. `chomp` only removes the character that matches the current value of `$/`, the input record separator. Which on most systems is `\n`.

Comment: So chomp is better... BUT I want to emphazise my sentence: Check subroutine caller's argument. If you want to write clean code, such a subroutine should not be expected to cut off something from its argument. Instead, the caller should provide an argument which contains a target name, not a target name followed by a newline.

Comment: @Mor You are right, that is also a way to solve it. He is probably reading the names from a file, and could chomp it there.